# Could someone show me the steps to rewrite this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{(a+h)^2 -a^2}{h} = \frac{(a + h-a)(a+h+a)}{h}$$

If I wanted to rewrite a different equation similar to the one above so I can reduce it what are the steps I need to take?

I keep getting stuck reducing these equation because unless I see a pattern I've seen before I don't know how to rewrite it in a way that can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Is usign the following result:
$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

for:$x=a+h$ and $y=a$

And also:

$\frac{(a+h)^2-a^2}{h}=\frac{a^2+2ah+h^2-a^2}{h}=\frac{2ah+h^2}{h}=2a+h$

Answer (score 1):

Hint $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ thats a one step simplification.